# Javascript List Item Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, step

I am working on a very basic animation where classes are removed from list items once they have been loaded and appended to the document. The issue I am having is with the animation itself. I want the animation to execute in a stepped manner like the image below...

[image: Animation I want]

What actually though is that the loop runs completely, console.log messages get output in a stepped manner, but the classes are all removed at the same time once the loop has completed. How can I change this behavior?  Why would the console.log messages be stepped but the classList.remove functionality is not executed at the same time?

Here is my code...

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}


/**/
function showListItems() {
  var listItems = document.querySelector('.idList');
  var n = 20;
  var c = 0;
  var itemArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.children.length; i++) {
    var item = listItems.children[i];
    if (item.classList && item.classList.contains('idList__item--hide')) {
      console.log('Item: ', item);
      itemArray[c] = item;
      c++;
    }
  }
  console.log('Item Array: ', itemArray);
  itemArray.forEach(function(el, index) {
    sleep(n);
    el.classList.remove('idList__item--hide');
    console.log("EL[" + index + "]: ", el);
  });
}
```

I realize this code may look over complex and perhaps it is, but I have tried about everything I can think of. I have tried using promises, for loops, now the forEach method.

Thank you.

Comment: Use incremental setTimeout. Note that using long blocking loops for `sleep()` is a really bad practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser doesn't update until javascript finishes running. Your script doesn't relinquished control back to the browser while sleeping so the browser can't update. This is exactly what `setTimeout` is for.

Change

```
itemArray.forEach(function(el, index) {
    sleep(n);
    el.classList.remove('idList__item--hide');
    console.log("EL[" + index + "]: ", el);
});
```

to

```
itemArray.forEach(function(el, index) {
    const ms = n * (index + 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.classList.remove('idList__item--hide');
        console.log("EL[" + index + "]: ", el);
    }, ms);
});
```

We're scheduling all the `remove` calls in advance which is why we're multiplying `n` by `index + 1`.

And in case you're interested, here is the code I used to test `sleep` vs `setTimeout`.
https://codepen.io/rockysims/pen/jeJggZ

Comment: Thank you for providing the explanation and example code. This seems to work great and makes a lot more sense now. Really simple once someone got me on the right track.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bad way but it should solve your problem.

You can use setTimeout() in forEach, and use index to change time parameter, like it:

```
itemArray.forEach(function(el, index) {
    setTimeout(function(){
         el.classList.remove('idList__item--hide')
    },500*(index+1)) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Jquery each and setTimeout functions for chaining the animations.

```js
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
    var listItem = $( this );
    setTimeout(function() {
      listItem.animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500); 
    }, (index + 1) * 500);
    
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding : 20px;
}
ul li {
  list-style : none;
  height : 50px;
  background-color : lightgreen;
  margin : 20px;
  opacity : 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>Hello world 1</li>
<li>Hello world 2</li>
<li>Hello world 3</li>
<li>Hello world 4</li>
</ul>
```